# jQuery: chosen 0.9.8

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I am using js-plugins "chosen 0.9.8" ([Chosen Plugin](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/)).

Issue: I want to group label like this:

[image]

I am using jQuery. I did also change its `placeholder` using

```
jQuery("#stEncryption").attr("data-placeholder","Select upto 3 levels");
```

Inline image 2 as a

[image]

Comment: So what are you facing the problem ? Can you create a fiddle of your code ?

Comment: @rahul, I want to Group label just like red round in image

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/ySdV8/)**

HTML code:

```
<div>
          <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
          <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
            <option value=""></option>
            <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
              <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
              <option>New York Giants</option>
              <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
              <option>Washington Redskins</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
              <option>Chicago Bears</option>
              <option>Detroit Lions</option>
              <option>Green Bay Packers</option>
              <option>Minnesota Vikings</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC SOUTH">
              <option>Atlanta Falcons</option>
              <option>Carolina Panthers</option>
              <option>New Orleans Saints</option>
              <option>Tampa Bay Buccaneers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="NFC WEST">
              <option>Arizona Cardinals</option>
              <option>St. Louis Rams</option>
              <option>San Francisco 49ers</option>
              <option>Seattle Seahawks</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC EAST">
              <option>Buffalo Bills</option>
              <option>Miami Dolphins</option>
              <option>New England Patriots</option>
              <option>New York Jets</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC NORTH">
              <option>Baltimore Ravens</option>
              <option>Cincinnati Bengals</option>
              <option>Cleveland Browns</option>
              <option>Pittsburgh Steelers</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC SOUTH">
              <option>Houston Texans</option>
              <option>Indianapolis Colts</option>
              <option>Jacksonville Jaguars</option>
              <option>Tennessee Titans</option>
            </optgroup>
            <optgroup label="AFC WEST">
              <option>Denver Broncos</option>
              <option>Kansas City Chiefs</option>
              <option>Oakland Raiders</option>
              <option>San Diego Chargers</option>
            </optgroup>
          </select>
        </div>
```

JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $(".chosen-select").chosen();
});
```

Comment: Then you should have indicated in your question that you are not using simple javascript or jquery in your project and instead using frameworks and also you should tag your questions appropriately !